# PHP Session Cookies stopped working on my server ONLY

Tags: php, session

I have a bizarre issue going on with my dev server.  Just a few hours ago PHP session just totally quit working.  Every single file (hundreds) started showing errors like below, about session cookies not being written.  I cannot figure out what the problem is, what cause this to just start happening, before everything worked and I haven't even made any changes.  Worse of all, I cannot get it working.  I tried different browsers, rebooting my server, rebooting my PC even.  Nothing helps, any ideas what I can do?  This is really crazy

Please note I do not have any white space or anything printing to screen before calling session_start() either

> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cookie - headers already sent
>   by (output started at
>   C:\webserver\htdocs\friendproject2\labs\2.php:1)
>   in
>   C:\webserver\htdocs\friendproject2\labs\2.php
>   on line 3
>
> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   C:\webserver\htdocs\friendproject2\labs\2.php:1)
>   in
>   C:\webserver\htdocs\friendproject2\labs\2.php
>   on line 3 test

As I mentioned, this happens on EVERY file of my site now, even simple files.  The error I posted is from a file as simple as this...

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
echo 
$_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo ini_get('safe_mode');` ?

Comment: Do you remember what you did before it stopped working?

Comment: @sberry2a echo ini_get('safe_mode'); does not print anything to screen

Comment: @sberry2A: How could that be part of the problem?

Comment: @Alix Axel I don't recall doing anything

Comment: @jasondavis: That means `safe_mode` is off, you should use `var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode'))` next time.

Comment: @Alix... it was just a hunch... something I saw somewhere once.  Anyway, how are the files being edited?  Locally in a text editor, or remotely on the server with emacs/vim?

Comment: @jasondavis: Did you change any `session_*` configuration directive in `php.ini` / `.htaccess`? Maybe implemented a custom session handler?

Comment: Locally, this is all ran on local server.  I been using phpdesigner, dreamweaver and for these simple test, notepad

Comment: @sberry2A: Good ideia! @jasondavis: Create a new `.php` file (in Notepad) with the following content: `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['test'] = 'test'; ?>` - what does it output?

Comment: @Alix Axel I havent done anything, thats why it is so weird, everything worked fine until it just changed a few hourse ago and I didnt chnage anything to cause it.  I am running my dev server live on the net with one of those services like no-ip.org or whatever, maybe someone could of hacked into my stuff and made a change? I doubt that would of happened hough everything else works fine

Comment: @Alix Axel that worked without any errors, weird

Comment: @jasondavis: Probably a non-printable char was being outputed, check the encoding of the file. Or just delete it and rewrite it (don't copy + paste, specially line #1).

Comment: @Alix Axel I just realized in notepad, the file I was making was UTF-8 and the file I made from your code was in ANSI.  SO I guess it has to be ANSI?

Comment: @Alix Axel my test file that was UTF-8 I just changed to ANSI and it works fine now too, thank god! maybe you should post this in your answer and Ill pick it

Comment: @jasondavis: No, you should always use UTF-8 encoding for your files, my guess is that your code editor was saving the files as **UTF-8 BOM**, should be **UTF-8 no BOM**.

Comment: @Alix Axel that is really weird then because ANSI makes it work in my notepad http://img2.pict.com/d4/b1/10/2604158/0/screenshot2b207.png

Comment: @jasondavis: ANSI will always work, but UTF-8 no BOM is preferred since it makes the process of i18n (internationalization) your application much more simpler.

Comment: All this encoding is new to me, I have never had to change any of it or anything

Comment: @jasondavis: I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Wow, this is the longest comment thread I have ever seen.  @Alix, yeah, I though this could be the proble, that's why I mentioned how the file was being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is getting outputed in line 1 of `C:\webserver\htdocs\friendproject2\labs\2.php`.

Also, where did that `test` came from?

---

Seems like the issue was the file encoding, you should always use **UTF-8 no BOM** as the prefered encoding for your `.php` files, code editors such as **[Intype](http://intype.info/home/index.php)** let you easily specify this (UTF-8 Plain).

[image]

---

**You should also read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky.**

Comment: I just updated my post with the actual code from that page.  The test is from the session variable, session work on a page if I set them on that page, just it wont send the cookie and is giving ther warning messages

Comment: UTF-* with no BOM is a partial solution but PHP expects its input in ASCII

Answer (score 0):

If the start_session() is in an include file check to make sure that you include that file BEFORE you output anything to the page. That is why it is saying the headers were already sent. I have had this issue before if the start_session() is not the very first thing.

Answer (score 0):

With no changes to the code and multiple pages affected, my first port of call would be to check if the webserver config (or php.ini or .htaccess) has had an auto-prepend added.

This would cause sberry2A's example code to fail. If sberry2A's code works, then check for some dodgy chars in a common include file.

C.